# How to plot a heat map or a contour plot from a matrix in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, heatmap, contour

I'm a `R` beginner. I made an operation between 2 vectors, and the result was a matrix. I'd like to plot a heat map or a contour plot using `ggplot2`. Any help?

```
library(ggplot2)

vector1 <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10)
vector2 <- c(0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30)

result <- matrix(0, nrow = length(vector2), ncol = length(vector1))
for (i in seq_len(length(vector2))) {
  for (j in seq_len(length(vector1))) {
    result[i,j] <- 1 + (vector2[i] * (vector1[j]))
  }
}
```

Example:

[image: plo]

Comment: According to linked post (reshape your data from wide to long and use `geom_tile`): `ggplot(reshape2::melt(result), aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() `

Comment: `result %>% as.table %>% data.frame` is equivalent to `reshape2::melt(result)` if you don't wanna use additional package.

Comment: @DarrenTsai That's a good point, however `melt` should be much faster (at least on bigger data).

Comment: @PoGibas it's worth noting that Hadley's said `reshape2` is deprecated in favor of `tidyr`

Comment: @Camille Thanks for pointing that. "Bad habits die hard" :)

Comment: @PoGibas I hated `melt` and `cast`, so it was easy to break that habit when `tidyr` came along